# Plasmashell freezes & crashes once restarted

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma

I have KDE 5 which worked well since 2 months.

Today it suddenly began holding 100% of one CPU core and won't stop restarting.

Every time when I log in, my taskbar and desktop totally freeze during about 30s then crash down together. Luckily the search application bar and other components are still working.

I saw these two questions :

- [Plasmashell keeps crashing [KUBUNTU]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/900308/plasmashell-keeps-crashing-kubuntu)
- [Why is plasmashell using 100% cpu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/846781/why-is-plasmashell-using-100-cpu)

And tried two methods inside :

```
killall plasmashell; kstart plasmashell; exit

sudo apt-add-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade -y
```

But it's always not better.

My environment :

```
Kubuntu 17.10
KDE Plasma 5.12.4
KDE Framework 5.44.0
Qt 5.9.1
Kernel 4.13.0-38-generic
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Well I found it.

```
kstart plasmashell
```

showed that crash always happened after clipboard widget initialization.

Indeed I've copied a huge text content(~55Mb) just before, which made the klipper widget unable to handle its history in ~/.local/share/klipper/.

By wiping that folder, every thing is back to normal now.

In my special case, I also unchecked this "Save clipboard contents on exit" option since I don't really need it : 
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iHNi.png)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You should report this as a bug so hopefully they do something about it in the next versions.

Comment: Reported, hope someone will work on it https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=399096